# Room Typeconverter Map<Int, IntArray>

Tags: android, kotlin

```
class MapConverters {
    @TypeConverter
    fun fromString(value: String): Map<Int, IntArray> {
        val mapType = object : TypeToken<Map<Int, IntArray>>() {}.type
        return Gson().fromJson(value, mapType)
    }

    @TypeConverter
    fun fromMap(map: Map<Int, IntArray>): String {
        val gson = Gson()
        return gson.toJson(map)
    }

}
```

```
@Entity
data class StartGame(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) val gameId: Int?,
    val gameName: String,
    val scoreList: Map<Int, IntArray>
)
```

```
@Database(
    entities = [StartGame::class, PersonList::class],
    version = 1,
    exportSchema = false
)
@TypeConverters(MapConverters::class){
...}
```

I got error

I want to put the Map type variable in Room.

I've tried many ways and tried to apply a typeConvertes.

But it didn't work well.

I'd like you to help me with this.

```
error: Not sure how to convert a Cursor to this method's return type (java.util.Map<java.lang.Integer, int[]>).
    public abstract java.util.Map<java.lang.Integer, int[]> getGameScoreBoardById(int gameId);
```

```
@Dao
interface DataDao {
...
    @Query("SELECT scoreList FROM StartGame WHERE gameId=:gameId")
    @TypeConverters(MapConverters::class)
    fun getGameScoreById(gameId: Int): Map<Int, IntArray>
```

```
D:\myapp\app_boardgame2\app\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\debug\com\wonddak\boardmaster\room\DataDao.java:20: error: Not sure how to convert a Cursor to this method's return type (java.util.Map<java.lang.Integer, int[]>).
    public abstract java.util.Map<java.lang.Integer, int[]> getGameScoreById(int gameId);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify which fields uses typeConverters in your model like -

```
@Entity
data class StartGame(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) val gameId: Int?,
    val gameName: String,
    @TypeConverters(MapConverters::class)
    val scoreList: Map<Int, IntArray>
)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.
But the same error occurs in DAO.

Comment: 1) Add DAO in Question , 2) remove typeConvertors from DAO , Room knows where to use them .

Comment: @WONDDAK If ans works , accept the ans and let others know it is right ans

Comment: I've been revising ever since.
It doesn't work out.
Store the string in the room.

It is solved by putting it directly through map<>json conversion before saving it.

Comment: @WONDDAK can you elaborate